# Как убрать точку в нумерации заголовков и рисунков?

Tags: latex

Пишу диплом на LaTeX, но не пользуюсь готовыми классами, поскольку у университета свои стандарты. Возникла проблема с заголовками - не обращал на неё внимания, пока не начал вставлять иллюстрации.

По стандарту заголовки должны иметь следующий формат: "1 НАЗВАНИЕ РАЗДЕЛА", "1.1 Название подраздела" и т.д. То же самое касается подписей к рисункам: "Рисунок 1 - Название рисунка".

Проблема заключается в точке в конце нумерации. По умолчанию получается "1. Название раздела" - и т.д. Гуглёж или даёт не то, что нужно, или ответы не помогают.

Дистрибутив: TeXLive

Компилятор: XeLaTeX

Пример кода:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % Кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage{xecyr}          %кириллические символы
\usepackage{graphicx} %пакет для вставки рисунков
\usepackage{float} %плавающие объекты
\usepackage{caption} %заголовки плавающих объектов

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}  %% устанавливает главный язык документа
\setotherlanguage{english} %% объявляет второй язык документа
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} %шрифты
\setsansfont{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\graphicspath{{pictures/}} %каталог со всеми картинками
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}    %разрешения изображений
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{deffis}{ -- } %разделитель объекта и названия
\captionsetup[figure]{format=plain, justification=centering, labelsep=deffis, figurewithin=none, name=Рисунок} %установки для картинок

%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
%эти команды не работают, точнее работают, но не влияет на точку

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Название главы}
    
    \section{Подзаголовок}
    
    Какой-то текст.
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{Шифр_Тритемиуса}
        \caption{Шифр Тритемиуса}
        \label{Tritem}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказалось в пакете polyglossia. По умолчанию он прописывает заголовки именно с точкой.

Решение следующее - нужно при выборе основного языка (именно русского, не знаю, работает ли с другими) добавить опцию "forceheadingpunctuation" со значением false.

В итоге код будет выглядеть так:

```
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа
```